# bash: eksctl: command not found. in centos 7

Tags: unix, centos7

I installed the eksctl with the help of this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-eksctl.html.
Commands I executed:-

> curl --silent --location "https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/releases/download/0.26.0-rc.1/eksctl_Linux_amd64.tar.gz" | tar xz -C /tmp

> sudo mv /tmp/eksctl /usr/local/bin

Output:-

> [shivani@vmunix ~]$ eksctl version

0.26.0-rc.1

> [root@vmunix ~]# eksctl version

bash: eksctl: command not found...

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

In case your issue is not resolved ,set the path as below :
Assuming eksctl binary is in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: And to sustain that behaviour in subsequent logins ... add "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/"  in your .bash_profile file

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me, we need to set a variable on the .bash_profile file

[root@ ~]# eksctl version
0.126.0